# ESLint `prop is missing in props validation` but it's there

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am building an `Input` whose props are derived from the HTML Input props. Everything should be type safe, and the IDE recognizes that `rest` contains all the HTML input props (even though I did not explicitly write them - thanks to the inheritance).
However, ESLint says they're not validated.

```
interface InputProps extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'> {
  ...
}

export const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
  (
    {
      value,
      // ^ This is where I get the ESLint error
      ...rest
    },
    ref
  ) => {
```

What's the correct thing to do here?

Comment: What ESLint rule is triggering this error? (The name is at the end of the error message)

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks Alex but I found a solution. Posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we remove the generic types passed to `forwardRef` and explicitly set the types for the function args, that solves the problem:

```
export const Input = React.forwardRef(
  (
    {
      value
    }: InputProps,
    ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
```